# RequireJS Optimizer - Cannot find function defineProperty

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm trying to concatenate my js files using the requirejs optimizer.

I'm basically following this tut:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m6VNhqKDM4E

This is in my build.js:

```
({
    baseUrl: "../",
    mainConfigFile: '../main.js',
    name: '../main',
    out: '../test.js',
    paths: {
        'jquery': [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min',
            // Fallback
            'libraries/jquery-1.11.1.min'
        ],
        'jquery-ui': [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min',
            // Fallback
            'libraries/jquery.ui.min'
        ],
        'jquery.browser': 'libraries/jquery.browser.min',
        'jquery.mousewheel': 'libraries/jquery.mousewheel.min',
        'modernizr': 'libraries/modernizr.min',
        'bootstrap-tooltip': 'libraries/bootstrap-tooltip',
        'parsley': 'libraries/parsley.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery-ui': [ 'jquery' ],
        'jquery.browser': {
            deps: [ 'jquery' ],
            exports: 'jQuery.fn.browser'
        },
        'jquery.mousewheel': [ 'jquery' ],
        'parsley': [ 'jquery' ]
    }
})
```

This is what I run in the terminal:

```
java -classpath js.jar org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main r.js -o build.js
```

But I get this error

```
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot find function defineProperty in object function Object() { [native code for Object.Object, arity=1] }
```

I have no clue and googling this doesn't give me anything I can work with. Hopefully u guys can help me.

Comment: Anybody with an answer?